# What are some metrics to compare which line is more "curved"?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, curves

Let's say we have two lines.  I want to compare which line is more "curved" over the same interval.  For example, let's say:

$f1(x) = x^2$

$f2(x) = sin(3x)$

Over the interval x = [0, 1], it is arguable, that f2(x) is more "curved".  What are some metrics to measure which two lines are more curved?  Curved can be a function of range(f(x)), how much f(x) changes direction, etc...

Are there any good ones out there?

Comment: How about second derivative?

Comment: [Curvature - graph of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Graph_of_a_function)